# Optimal power supply for RF switch

Tags: power-supply, switches

I am planning to use an RF switch to pulse a signal >1GHz. Specifically, I'm interested in the ZASWA-2-50DR switch from Minicircuits (http://194.75.38.69/pdfs/ZASWA-2-50DR+.pdf) due to the low rise time that should ramp the signal within a few cycles. Now, all in- and outputs are SMA, including the +-5V supply. I have not seen this before and am a bit puzzled on what power supply and adapters to use. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: "due to the low rise time that should ramp the signal within a few cycles. " You lost me there, what do you mean ? Read the spec. it says it will take a maximum of 20 ns to switch. At 1 GHz that is 20 periods. SMA connectors should be no problem but you will have to make your own connection to a power supply. Are you expecting a power supply with an SMA output connector ? Forget about that, these don't exist.

Comment: But cables with BNC or banana plugs on one end and SMA on the other end do exist.

Comment: Or look at ZASWA2-50DR-FT+ instead. It looks like the same amplifier but with solder posts instead of SMA connectors for power.

Comment: @FakeMoustache yes, the spec says 10ns switch time, or ~10 periods, which is an acceptable number of "distorted" periods and much lower than other switches I've found. The connector is exactly my question. I assumed there'd be no SMA power supply, but I don't know what the best alternative is.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'll have to look for these. <s>The other model might also be an option, thanks!</s>
Actually, the FT+ is no good, as I'll need the TTL input for the pulses.

Comment: what an absurd datasheet!

Comment: If the switch needs to act in 10 or 20 ns, then the control signal rise time must be under 10 ns. The control signal path had better carry frequency components well above 100 MHz. This is why they use SMA for the control signals, a bit of wire soldered to a post wouldn't cut it. Another reason to use RF connectors is to prevent noise pick-up. An unshielded power lead flying over ground to the switch would act as an antenna, contaminating your signal with all sorts of environmental signals, especially GSM.